# live tile is not updating in Windows Phone

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

i am developing a windows phone app where application has an option to pin the application to home screen. And i am using ShellTileSchedule class to do schedule the update periodically. Some reason my app is not pushing any update to tile. My app data is completely local, no data is coming from outside.

In my tile update, i am not updating any image on the lile, but only changing the data to display.

```
 foreach (ShellTile tile in ShellTile.ActiveTiles)
 {
            IconicTileData tileData = GetTileData();

            tileSchedule = new ShellTileSchedule(tile, tileData);
            tileSchedule.Interval = UpdateInterval.EveryHour;
            tileSchedule.Recurrence = UpdateRecurrence.Interval;
            tileSchedule.Count=GetUserData();
            tileSchedule.StartTime = DateTime.Now;
            tileSchedule.Start();

            tile.Update(tileData);
}
```

Any help in this regard? Or do i need to background agent to update the tile?

Comment: Given the interval is an hour, I hope you are aware of it'll not push any updates before 60 minutes *after* you run the code.

Comment: yes, i aware of this. I tried and but updates never pushed.

Comment: Why don't you use the `Cycle Tile Template` - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj207036(v=vs.105).aspx _[It will cycle through between 1 & 9 images]_

Comment: @AngshumanAgarwal thanks, i considered this option. But i am not pushing or displaying any images as i mentioned in the question to the live except the app icon.

Comment: May be you can have a look at this Build 2012 video on `Windows Phone 8: Tiles, Lock Screen, and Notifications` - http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Build/2012/2-019. Entire source code is available here to tweak around - http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tfennel/archive/2012/11/13/windows-phone-8-notifications-and-tiles-intro.aspx

Comment: thanks @AngshumanAgarwal it's good source, will take a look into this example.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> ShellTileSchedule can only pull images off the web, not from the phone itself. This is one of the limitations of ShellTileSchedule. If you want to set background images to resources on the phone, look at using push notifications instead.

Source: http://www.silverlightshow.net/news/WP7-Using-ShellTileSchedule-to-update-your-app-s-Live-Tile-background.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Shouldn't you be setting a ShellTileSchedule.RemoteImageUri somewhere? I mean, that's kinda what ShellTileSchedule is there for, to update your tile image from a remote Uri on a regular interval... See sample of how to use this class for secondary tiles [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff769548%28v=vs.105%29.aspx#BKMK_SchedulingSecondaryTiles).

Comment: actually, i do not need any image to show in the app. Do you think, is it causing the error? and also, if need to use this what is dimensions of the image?

Comment: Well, yeah. The only thing ShellTileSchedule is useful for is to update the images on start screen tiles from a remote URL. If you don't need that feature, why are you using ShellTileSchedule?

Comment: well, i am using ShellTileSchedule to update the tile content only. I am not using/pulling any remote images. Is there any other option to achieve the same?

Answer (score 0):

You have to fill the properties of IconicTileData. In your sample you just create empty data structure and use it for the schedule, that won't work. I use it like this:

```cs
IconicTileData newTileData = new IconicTileData
{
    Title = SharedResources.AppName,
    Count = BatteryHelper.BateryLevel,
    SmallIconImage = new Uri(@"/Assets/IconicSmall.png", UriKind.Relative),
    IconImage = new Uri(@"/Assets/IconicMedium.png", UriKind.Relative),
};
```

Comment: i filled IconicTileData in my GetTileData() method with similar data. But my scheduler never fires to update the data. I see an additional line RemoteImageURI is missing in my definition, so i wonder is it causing the issue?