# IconicTile not getting updated in windows phone 8.0

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone, push-notification, live-tile, mpns

I have defined IconicTile Template as default tile for my Application. Now I wish to update my tile with the notification count. So I have sent following parameters for the update:

```
backgroundColor,
count,
title,
iconImage,
smallIconImage,
wideContent1,
wideContent2,
wideContent3
```

Tile update works fine on the test device running on windows phone 8.1 but its not coming up on device and emulators running on windows phone 8.0. What am I missing here? Please help

Answer (score 0):

Are you targeting your application for `WP8` or `WP8.1`?

Try adding this snippet in your class.

```
IconicTileData TileData = new IconicTileData()
{
Title = "[title]",
Count = [count],
WideContent1 = "[1st row of content]",
WideContent2 = "[2nd row of content]",
WideContent3 = "[3rd row of content]",
SmallIconImage = [small Tile size URI],
IconImage = [medium/wide Tile size URI],
BackgroundColor = [.NET color type of Tile]
};
```

Hope this [live tile is not updating in Windows Phone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13280863/) helps.

Comment: Hey Sorry for late reply. There was some server side issue actually. Thanks for reply